# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument 'address'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code. I have this erro message:
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'address'
what do you think seems to be the problem?

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, name, address):
    self.name = name
    self.address = address

def say_name(self):
    print('Hello, my name is', self.name)
def say_address(self):
    print('Hello, my name address', self.address)

p = Person('Swaroop')
q = Person('Duisburg')

p.say_name()
q.say_address()
```

Comment: Rather, you are not providing the name.

Comment: Your class requires 2 parameters, `name` and `address`. Not one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__` is declared as taking a `name` and an `address`:

```
def __init__(self, name, address):
```

This means that you need to provide both of them, so the following is not valid:

```
p = Person('Swaroop')
```

If you have use cases where the address cannot be provided, then you can make the argument optional:

```
def __init__(self, name, address=None):
```

The above statement will give `address` a default value of `None` if the argument is not provided.

---

Taking a closer look at your code it seems you wanted to provide a name and an address as two separate objects:

```
p = Person('Swaroop') # name
q = Person('Duisburg') # address
```

Note that arguments are identified by position, so on `q`, `Duisburg` will correspond to the `name` argument.

You can achieve what you want by using just one object:

```
p = Person('Swaroop', 'Duisburg')
p.say_name()
p.say_address()
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)   
        conn.close()

class Person(object): 
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name  

    def getName(self): 
        return self.name 

class Employee(Person): 
    def __init__(self, name, age): 
        Person.__init__(self, name) 
        self.age = age 

    def getAge(self): 
        return self.age 

class main(Employee): 

    def __init__(self, name, age, address): 
        Employee.__init__(self, name, age) 
        self.address = address 

    def display(self):
        print(self.name, self.age, self.address)

    def getAddress(self): 
        return self.address 

    def view_all_empdata(conn): 
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM empdata")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row)

    def main():
        database = "/home/vandana/Desktop/PythonDatabase/Emp2"
        conn = create_connection(database)
        with conn:
            print("View All Employee")
            select_all_emp(conn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```